[Accepted answer]Cordova SDK problem with com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0
Recently, I have this error message from Google :
`com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0
Google Play Core (com.google.android.play:core) has added this note for SDK version 1.10.0:
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration
From September 21, 2024 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release new versions of your app containing this SDK version to production or open testing.`
I tried many updates of cordova version, but nothing is running.

You can follow the following steps, as suggested in my own answer here
Go to your android folder
cd /platforms/android

Run the gradle command to check dependencies
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt

And look for the above dependency that has the warning, and then you can find an update or remove the depdendency that is causing the issue

Many thanks, I searched into plugins directory and found "cordova-plugin-native-app-update" that needed to be updated.
